# initializer is being unused to append data (swift3)

Tags: swift, initialization, append, init

I am trying to append whatever is in both textfields to the MyData set. However there is a error message coming back to me stating that

> MyData.init(company: textA.text!, scorej: Int(textB.text!)!) is being unused.

How can I append this data?

```
import UIKit

struct MyData {
   var company = String()
   var scorej: Int
}

var data = [
   MyData(company: "smiths", scorej: 4),
   MyData(company: "lukes", scorej: 4),
]

let sortedArray = data.sorted(by: { ($0.company, $1.scorej) < ($1.company, $0.scorej) })

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var textB: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet var textA: UITextField!

   @IBAction func store(_ sender: Any) {
      MyData.init(company: textA.text!, scorej: Int(textB.text!)!)
      print(sortedArray)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unuesed means that something has returned something and you haven't used it.

```
MyData(company: textA.text!, scorej: Int(textB.text!)!)
```

Wasn't used anywhere, by that it mean :

```
let yourObject = MyData(company: textA.text!, scorej: Int(textB.text!)!)
```

and `yourObject` is not used any where in code, in case to tell the compiler that you are not willing to use it for now, to avoid that is an easy way :

```
let _ = MyData(company: textA.text!, scorej: Int(textB.text!)!)
```

The `_`- tells the compiler that you are not going to use it. For example it's handy for handling `nil` variables in the `if` condition.

**Edit**

Acording for what you said, please append newly created object inside `store` function and then sort it once more.

Comment: This does not cause a error but a new each is not added to MyData. Its still just 2 entries when using let _ = MyData(company: textA.text!, scorej: Int(textB.text!)!)

Comment: So what you wanna do with `MyData(company: textA.text!, scorej: Int(textB.text!)!)` ?

Comment: I want it to be the 3rd entry in the var data set. Right now there are just two entries. I want to spend it to that data set.